# For loop to create multiple buttons is not working

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, jlabel

Recently I have tried to add buttons to an array of JLabels, that are getting put into a JPanel (which is in JFrame). For some reason, (I am running eclipse) I get a compiler error which cuts off at this line: me[f].add(new JButton(" "));. I am having trouble in getting an array of buttons to get placed into the panel (panel1). Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 package Grid;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 public class Grid {
private static int width;
private static int length;
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
public static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private static JButton but[] = new JButton[width*length];
private static JFrame window = new JFrame();
public static void Gridify(int width,int length){
    //frame.setSize(500,500);   
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setEnabled(true); 
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length));
        panel1.setVisible(true);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    frame.add(panel1);  
}
public void manualPanels(int num){
    for(int f=0; f < num;f++){
    JPanel me[] = new JPanel[f];
    me[f].add(new JButton(" "));
    me[f].setVisible(true);
    panel1.add(me[f]);
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

 }
```

Comment: What is this compiler error you get?

Comment: Should the JPanel array be declared before the loop?

Comment: My goal is to create 'f' amount of JLabels into panel1. I ultimately want to put images into the Jlabels so people can click on tiles of images. Is there possibly a better alternative to using JLabels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in this line:

```
me[f].add(new JButton(" "));
```

First, `me[f]` do not exists, as your array goes from 0 to f-1.

Second, your array is full of `null` (since you just created it). So, would you write, say `me[0]`, you would still get an error.

In order to create `num` new `JPanel`s and put them into `panel1`, you need to do the following:

```
for (int f = 0; f < num; f++) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(panel);
}
```

Comment: So how do you propose I fix it? My goal is to generate a bunch of Labels in panel1. What does the correct code look like? I also pass in a value (num) when I call the method, so how is it counting from f-1, when it is really 0-f...

Comment: @user2581598 if an answer works for you, you are supposed to accept it.